# Doctrine 2: is it possible to define an association to another entity using multiple columns for the join?

Tags: doctrine-orm

Here's the use case: I have an Address table that has a fk_id field and a type field. That table can be related to several other tables. So for example, if I want to store an address for a person, I'd set the fk_id field to the person_id value and set the type field to 'person'. For a company, I'd set fk_id to the company_id value and type to 'company'. And so on.

So if I wanted to define a one-to-one relationship on the Person entity, is it possible? Or do you absolutely need a direct relationship only between the two tables? I suspect that's the case, but figured I'd make sure.

Secondly, if it's not possible, is there any way I can run a query (using DQL or QueryBuilder) to retrieve a Person and associated Address entity(ies) in a format like this:

```
[
    { person_id: 1, person_name: 'John', addresses: [{ address_id: 1, address_street: '1 Main St' }] },
    { person_id: 2, person_name: 'Tim', addresses: [{ address_id: 2, address_street: '2 Main St' }] }
]
```

I tried with the query builder, the problem is that when I do the join from Person to Address, I do something like this:

```
->join('address', 'a', Join::ON, "p.person_id = a.fk_id AND a.type = 'person'")
```

I get an error, apparently because of the Join::ON. if I use Join::WITH, it works fine, but then I get the email record as a separate item in the array, which is pretty inconvenient.

Here is what the query would look like in regular SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM person p 
    INNER JOIN address a ON a.fk_id = p.person_id AND a.type = 'person'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How would this query look like in native SQL?

Comment: Just added the query in native SQL.

Comment: Are you sure that query works? AFAIK you have to use the AS keyword if you want to alias tables.

Comment: Yeah, it works. And no, you don't need the AS keyword to alias tables.